# random git comments on aliases

Tags: git, pipe, aliases

I am using

```
git commit -m "`fortune`"
```

for redirecting the output of the fortune script to my commit when I am running short of imagination. As it happens this arrives quite frequently so I decided to add it to the git alias. But is not working. It writes fortune always in my commit which is boring, how to fix this?

Comment: why don't you do the git command in your `fortune` script itself? something like `os.system("git commit -m " + "your message")`

Comment: Of course I can do that but hte questions is more about scaping charactes in bash when they are sent to git.

Comment: probably Git commit -m "$(./fortune)" or something similar?

Comment: Are you talking about the `[alias]` section in your `.gitconfig` or `.git/config` file? If so, note that aliases only use the shell at all if you start them with `!`.

Comment: @torek, that is it! I put random = !git commit -m \"`fortune`\" into my .gitconfig and it works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to torek for the hint. I just put this into my .gitconfig, into the alias section:

```
random = !git commit -m \"`fortune`\"
```